# How can I fill in missing values (NaN) at a particular column in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe of which one column contains several missing values, which are printed as NaN. I want to replace the missing values with the number 0. How can I do that with the *fillna()* function?

Comment: `df ['my_column']= df['my_column'].fillna(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

does using data.fillna(0) work for you?